# Regex values after special character with empty values

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am struggle with regex to split spring into columns in Oracle database.

```sql
select (REGEXP_SUBSTR(replace('1:::9999', ' ',''), '[^: ]+', 1, 4)) from dual;
```

I need to obtain 4th value from that string as a column value, sometimes values at position 2,3 are empty and my query doesn't work. I am trying to figure out what regex will work

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL?  Such as MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
select (REGEXP_SUBSTR(replace('1:::9999', ' ',''), '([^: ]*)(:|$)', 1, 4, 'i', 1)) from dual;
```

Here, the `([^: ]*)(:|$)` matches

- `([^: ]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `:` and space
- `(:|$)` - Group 2, either `:` or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a (slower) regex for this task, use simple `substr/instr` functions:

```
with input_(val) as (
  select '1:::9999' from dual
  union all
  select '1:2::' from dual
  union all
  select '1:2::3:5' from dual
)
, replaced as (
  select input_.*, replace(val, ' ', '') as val_replaced
  from input_
)
select
  val,
  substr(
    val_replaced,
    /*Locate the first occurrence of a colon and get a substring ...*/
    instr(val_replaced, ':', 1, 3) + 1,
    /*.. until the end, if the next colon is absent, or until the next colon*/
    nvl(nullif(instr(val_replaced, ':', 1, 4), 0), length(val_replaced) + 1) - instr(val_replaced, ':', 1, 3) - 1
  ) as col
from replaced
```

| VAL | COL |
| --- | --- |
| 1:::9999 | 9999 |
| 1:2:: | *null* |
| 1:2::3:5 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lgz5YoJm) with performance difference.